# how to set flash messages in my custom MVC framework?

Tags: php, session, model-view-controller

this is the Session class in Session.php file

```
<?php 


namespace app\core;

class Session
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
    }

    public function setFlash($key='', $message='')
    {
        $_SESSION['flash'][$key] = $message;
    }

    public function getFlash($key='')
    {

        return $_SESSION['flash'][$key] ?? false;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        unset($_SESSION['flash']);
    }
}
```

then i called session::setFlash() before redirecting the user to the home page after registering
and call session::getFlash() in the view or the layout does not matter but i displayed nothing

here is the code

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $registerModel = new RegisterModel;


        if($request->isPost())
        {
            $registerModel->loadData($request->getBody());

            if($registerModel->validate() && $registerModel->save())
            {
                Application::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thanks for registering');
                $this->redirect('.');
            }

            return $this->render('register', [
                'model' => $registerModel
            ]);
        }

        $this->setLayout('auth');
        return $this->render('register', [
            'model' => $registerModel
        ]);
    }
```

this the view

```
 <div class="container">

    <?php if(Application::$app->session->getFlash('success')):?>

    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <?php echo Application::$app->session->getFlash('success'); ?>
    </div>

   <?php endif; ?>
      {{content}}
   </div>
```

i don`t know why it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Two probable suspects:

1. You are unsetting the `'flash'` index when destructing the session. This means that when ONE request ends (the first one), the data is cleared. I'd recommend you rather remove a specific key from this array when calling `getFlash()`, so that every message is only gotten once.
2. When the second request is already handled but the session was not written to the storage yet (which is usually handled asynchronously by PHP), you may want to add a call to [`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php). This immediately ends the session and writes data to the session storage directly, making it available for the second request (the one that comes *after* the redirect). You have to call this *before* making the redirect.

**Side note:** Your "custom MVC framework" code looks like it could live inside Laravel. If it does, the `redirect()` method may already call the `session_write_close()` so my second point would be moot.

Comment: thanks alot it works my bro this a new info that i learnt from u thanks again

Comment: @abdallahquapeel You are always welcome to upvote and/or accept answers that solved your problem.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot my bro @ArSeN by default session data is stored in session storage but usually the file that the server stores session data in is locked and we use session_write_close() to unlock the file as i used session before and did not need this function that i have read in PHP documentation note [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#122035]